# removing and object from an array by calling its object name

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array
Telephone[] Telephones = new Telephone[5]

I create a new telephone that i send in the array

```
Telephone tel1 = new Telephone("jim","bush","1234567",0);
Telephone tel2 = new Telephone("joe","bush","1111111",0);
Telephone tel3 = new Telephone("jane","bush","4444444",0);
```

Now array is like this

```
Telephones = [tel1, tel2, tel3, null, null]
```

I want to remove tel2 not by using its index but rather it's object name tel2.
because over time tel2 will move position in the array so i will not know its index anymore.
is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a `Map` for holding these `Telephone`.

```
public final class Telephone {

    private final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String phone;
    private final int code;

    public Telephone(String firstName, String lastName, String phone, int code) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public UUID UUID() {
        return uuid;
    }
}
```

---

```
// create a telephone
Telephone tel1 = new Telephone("jim", "bush", "1234567", 0);
Telephone tel2 = new Telephone("joe", "bush", "1111111", 0);
Telephone tel3 = new Telephone("jane", "bush", "4444444", 0);

// create and keep a phone book
Map<UUID, Telephone> phoneBooks = new HashMap<>();

// add telephone to the phone book by unique key
phoneBooks.put(tel1.UUID(), tel1);
phoneBooks.put(tel2.UUID(), tel2);
phoneBooks.put(tel3.UUID(), tel3);

// remove telephone from the phone book by unique key
phoneBooks.remove(tel1.UUID());
```